# 2D Shooter using JPanel/JFrame. drawImage (bullet) on screen with it's own velocity

Tags: java, swing, graphics, nullpointerexception, jpanel

Here is what I have:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener, ImageObserver {
        public Image ship;
        public Image enemy;
        private int xLoc;
        private int yLoc = 180;
        private int xLoc2 = 700;
        private int yLoc2 = 180;
        private int xVel;
        private int yVel;
        private int xVel_en;
        private int xVel_sh = 6;
        private ImageObserver observer = null;
        private ArrayList<Base> shield = new ArrayList<Base>();
        private Image shieldPiece;
        private Shot shot;

        public GamePanel()  {
            ship = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("ship3.png");
            enemy = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("alien-ship-1.png");
            shieldPiece = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("block2.png");

            for(int x = 500; x < 680; x = x + 18)
                for(int y = 60; y < 370; y = y + 18)    {
                    Base temp = new Base(x,y);
                    shield.add(temp);
                }
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g){
            super.paint(g);
            g.drawImage(ship, xLoc, yLoc, null);
            g.drawImage(enemy, xLoc2, yLoc2, null);

            for(Base b: shield)
                g.drawImage(shieldPiece, b.getShieldX(), b.getShieldY(), null);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            move();
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            repaint();

        }

        private void move() {

            int endOfWindow = getWidth();
            int endOfWindow1 = getHeight();
            if(xLoc>=(endOfWindow - ship.getWidth(null))|| xLoc<0)
                xVel = -xVel;
            xLoc +=xVel;    
            if(xLoc>=(endOfWindow - ship.getWidth(null)))
                xVel = -xVel;
            xLoc +=xVel;
            if(yLoc>=(endOfWindow1 - ship.getHeight(null)) || yLoc<0)
                yVel = -yVel;
            yLoc +=yVel;
            if(yLoc>=(endOfWindow1 - ship.getHeight(null)))
                yVel = -yVel;
            yLoc +=yVel;

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D)
                xVel = 3;
            if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A)
                xVel = -3;
            if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W)
                yVel = -3;
            if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S)
                yVel = 3;

            if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
                xVel = 3;
            if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
                xVel = -3;
            if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
                yVel = -3;
            if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
                yVel = 3;

            if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)  {
                Shot shoot = new Shot(xVel_sh, xLoc, yLoc);
                shoot.paint();

            }


        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D || arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A)
                xVel = 0;
            if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W || arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S)
                yVel = 0;

            if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
                xVel = 0;
            if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP || arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
                yVel = 0;

        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
}
```

and the Shot class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;


public class Shot{
    private int xVel_sh;
    private int xCoord;
    private int yCoord;
    private Image shot;
    private Graphics g;

    public Shot(int vel, int xLoc, int yLoc)    {
        vel = xVel_sh;
        xCoord = xLoc;
        yCoord = yLoc;
        shot = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("shot4.png");
    }

    public void setShotVel(int shotVel) {
        xVel_sh = shotVel;
    }

    public void paint() {
        g.drawImage(shot, xCoord, yCoord, null);
    }
}
```

I have it set up so when I hit space, it should create a shot object, then call the paint() method in the Shot class.  The shot object would be created at xLoc and yLoc (from GamePanel class - which is the location of the "ship" or player).

However, I get a lot of errors, starting with a NullPointerException when I hit space.  The game does not crash, it just keeps coming up with a null pointer exception.'  It is also followed by this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Shot.paint(Shot.java:25)
    at GamePanel.keyPressed(GamePanel.java:104)
    at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Not really sure why it is not being drawn...can anyone help?  Also, I need to eventually implement object collisions (with a shield class not shown here)...so if anyone has any direction towards tutorials on that? :P

Comment: You would debug your NPE just like any NPE -- find out what line is throwing it, then find out which variable on that line is null, and then trace back in your program to find out why it's null. Good luck.

Comment: You should never maintain a reference to any `Graphics` context (especially any you didn't create).  You should also dispose of any `Graphcis` contexts you have create as soon as you have finished using them as they can consume resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`g` is never initialized in `Shot`, so when you call `g.drawImage` it throws a `NullPointerException`.